# convolution of $f$ and $g$ is in $L^p$ where $f$ has compact support.

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Suppose 1≤p≤∞ and $f∈L^1(G)$ and $g∈L^p(G)$.

I know this is true $‖f*g‖_p ≤‖f‖_1 ‖g‖_q$ , Where ∗ is convolution of f and g.

I want to prove that If G is not unimodular, we still have g∗f is in LP when f has compact support.

proof:

By definition convolution we have $$‖g*f‖_p=‖∫g(xy^{-1} )f(y)∆(y^{-1} )dy‖ ≤∫‖g(xy^{-1})‖_p |f(y)|∆(y^{-1} )dy $$

since the LP norm is left-invariant $$ =‖g‖_p ∫f(y)∆(y^{-1} )dy$$ I know that integral out of support f is zero. But I do not know how can prove that value of the integral is finite

Comment: The modular function is [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#The_modular_function), hence bounded on compact sets. Am I overlooking something?