# Non-unitary representation

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

How to prove $\pi :\mathbb R\to \mathbb C^2$,   defined by $t\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t\\  0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is a non-unitary representation?

Is the following correct? $\pi$ is a representation because 
$$\pi (t+s)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & t+s \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & t\\  0  &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & s \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}  = \pi(t)\pi(s)$$

For non-unitary, I need to prove $U:\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb C^2$ is not unitary.

Answer (score 2):

For $\pi$ to be a unitary representation, $\pi(x)$ must be a unitary matrix for every element $x$ of the group. Here, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
is not a unitary matrix unless $t=0$. Indeed,
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^* \begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} 
=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \bar t & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}   = \begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ \bar t & 1+|t|^2\end{pmatrix} $$   which is not the identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you for editing and answers. 
can You  edit the following two posts?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783268/convolution-of-f-and-g-is-in-lp-where-f-has-compact-support

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783643/suppose-g-is-unimodular-if-f-is-in-lpg-and-g-is-in-lqg-where-1-p-q-an

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** this post largely composed before user147263 graciously corrected the equation in user147972's original question.  See below for details.  ***End of Note.***

So we have that

$\pi(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}$

and thus

$\pi(s + t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s + t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{2}$

which shows that $\pi$ is a homomorphism from the additive group of real numbers to the multiplicative group of real $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & t\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}. \tag{3}$

We note in passing that the OP apparently made an error in writing the equation

$\pi(ts) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & ts \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s + t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{4}$

since

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & ts \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{5}$

and furthermore (4) implies $st = s + t$, clearly false for arbitrary $s, t \in \Bbb R$.  So, rather than bandy these points about in the comment stream, waiting until they were straightened out, I made the leap of faith as it were and tried to infer what was intended from my general mathematical background and common sense; hope I got it right!  Meanwhile I would like to suggest to user147972 that he/she carefully reconsider the equation for $\pi(ts)$ proferred in the question as stated, and to consider a judicious edit if he/she agrees witn my assessment.  In any event, we return to the (non-)unitarity of $\pi(t)$.  A unitary matrix $U$ may be defined by the fact that $U^\dagger U = UU^\dagger = I$, where $U^\dagger$  is the hermitian adjoint of $U$; as is well-known, $U^\dagger$ is given by taking the *conjugate transpose* of $U$; that is, writing

$U = [u_{ij}] \tag{6}$

we have

$(U^\dagger)_{ij} = \bar u_{ji}, \tag{7}$

or, in terms of (6),

$U^\dagger = [\bar u_{ij}]^T = [\bar u_{ji}]. \tag{8}$

For any $t \in ,\Bbb C$ we thus may compute $\pi(t)^\dagger \pi(t)$ as follows:

$\pi(t)^\dagger \pi(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \bar t & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ \bar t & 1 + \bar t t \end{bmatrix} = I \Leftrightarrow t = 0; \tag{9}$

this shows that $\pi(t)$ is not unitary for $0 \ne t \in \Bbb C$, hence certainly not for $0 \ne t \in \Bbb R$.  ***QED.***

And this is how we show that $\pi(t)$ is not in general unitary!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you very much. Before asking a question that has no answer to it. Might help me

Comment: @user147972:  you're welcome of course; as for the rest of your comment, I'm having a little trouble parsing it.  Did you mean the original version had no answer due to the erroneous equation?

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783268/convolution-of-f-and-g-is-in-lp-where-f-has-compact-support

Comment: @user147972:  let me put it like this:  what question had no answer?

Comment: and this.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783643/suppose-g-is-unimodular-if-f-is-in-lpg-and-g-is-in-lqg-where-1-p-q-an

Comment: @uset147972:  got it!  OK I'll check them out!

Comment: You really made me a big favor

Comment: @user147972:  thanks.  This may take a little while, so I beg your patience!

Comment: ok . it is good.thank you